# Removing elements in a list given a matrix which references these elements

Tags: python

I have both an array and a matrix. Both of them reference the same set of objects, but in different ways.

Say my list contains the elements:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

My matrix would reference the same 9 integers, but like this:

```
[[3,6,8],
[2,9,4],
[5,1,7]]
```

The problem I'm facing is: I need a way to pop edges from the list, given the matrix which points to the same objects that are located in the list. Or, in other words, say I need to remove matrix[1][1], I wish to also be able to remove array[8], but I don't know the index of this object in the list, I only know the object itself and that it is referenced at by some index in the list.

Comment: words, words, words. Would be a lot clearer with some specific code and example...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I decided to rewrite the question entirely in order to be mroe generic.

Comment: show your code what you tried and errors

Comment: Also you question is still most unclear. I don't see any sort of reference here.

Comment: You can't depend on the address, which has the same value object doesn't mean always refer to the same object.

Comment: Sincerely, I have no idea how to begin since I'm fairly new to Python. I have a code that originally used only an array as a way to generate polygons out of edges in this array, but the code was really inefficient, since I basically had to run through the entire list to find edges which were able to connect. Using an matrix, I  only need to search the 4 nearest cells in the grid, which would greatly increase efficiency, but I have no idea how to find the edges in the array to remove if they are used in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a different data structure altogether -- a dict. The time complexity of doing a lookup on your data structures will become prohibitive at scale.

**Example:**

```
import random                                                                                       

random.seed(0)                                                                                      

edges = [(6, 3), (5, 4), (1, 2), (0, 1), (3, 5), (2, 0), (4, 6)]                                    
graph = {}                                                                                          
for i, j in edges:                                                                                  
    graph[i] = j                                                                                    

results = []                                                                                        
while graph:                                                                                        
    result = []                                                                                     
    i = random.choice(list(graph.keys()))                                                           
    while i in graph:                                                                               
        j = graph.pop(i)                                                                            
        result.append((i, j))                                                                       
        i = j                                                                                       
    results.append(result)                                                                          

print(edges)                                                                                        
print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
[(6, 3), (5, 4), (1, 2), (0, 1), (3, 5), (2, 0), (4, 6)]
[[(4, 6), (6, 3), (3, 5), (5, 4)], [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]]
```